# Error while exporting the pdf report from jasper xml in Websphere 8.5 Application server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, itext, websphere-8

We have deployed the application ear in Websphere 8.5 successfully under Linux platform. Application started with out any issue and we are able to access the application.But when we export the pdf report we are getting

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.lowagie.text.DocumentException

even though the itext-1.01.jar file in the ear context path and added the jar in MENIFEST.MF file of reports.jar(EJB).

Below the exception trace for the issue..

> RemoteExcepti E   CNTR0020E: EJB threw an unexpected (non-declared)
>   exception during invocation of method "printReport" on bean
>   "BeanId(APPLICATION#reports.jar#xxxx_xxxx_xxxx_reports_ReportEJB,
>   null)". Exception data: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com.lowagie.text.DocumentException    at
>   java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:94)     at
>   java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:171)    at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(JasperExportManager.java:183)
>     at xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.JasperReportUtil.exportReport(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.JasperReportUtil.printReport(Unknown Source)
>     at xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxxx.ReportEJB.printReport(Unknown Source)   at
>   xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.EJSRemoteStatelessxxxx_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx_ReportEJB_ed5d2a50.printReport(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx._Report_Stub.printReport(_Report_Stub.java:273)
>     at
>   xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.ReportAction.print(ReportAction.java:992)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)     at
>   org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:269)
>     at xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.CLookupDispatchAction.execute(Unknown
>   Source)

Any suggestions..Thanks.

Comment: iText 1.0.1 dates from October 2003. That is *more than 14 years ago!* The current version of iText, is iText 7. I am the Lowagie you refer to in your question (`com.lowagie`) and I can tell you with 99.9% certainty that no one can help you with a version that old.

Comment: Thanks for the response.I agree with you, but the itext-1.01.jar is working perfect in Prod environment under the same configuration. Surprisingly the same is not working in Dev environment.